# image_picker picking image in android and app crashing

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I just implement latest plugin of `image_picker` and below is simple code

```
Future getImage({String from}) async {
    var image;
    if (from == 'camera') {
      image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
          source: ImageSource.camera);
    } else {
      image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
          source: ImageSource.gallery);
    }
    if (image == null) return;

    setState(() {
      _adVertData.image = image;
    });

  }
```

getting crash

```
D/AndroidRuntime(31145): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(31145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(31145): Process: com.mobileapp.sin, PID: 31145
E/AndroidRuntime(31145): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2342, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:134427 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.mobileapp.sin/com.mobileapp.sin.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property callbackManager has not been initialized
E/AndroidRuntime(31145):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4361)
E/AndroidRuntime(31145):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4403)
E/AndroidRuntime(31145):    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime(31145):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime(31145):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(31145):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
E/AndroidRuntime(31145):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(31145):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
E/AndroidRuntime(31145):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
E/AndroidRuntime(31145):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(31145):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(31145):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/AndroidRuntime(31145): Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property callbackManager has not been initialized
E/AndroidRuntime(31145):    at com.mobileapp.sin.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:80)
E/AndroidRuntime(31145):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7458)
E/AndroidRuntime(31145):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4354)
E/AndroidRuntime(31145):    ... 11 more
I/Process (31145): Sending signal.
```

Comment: where is your  `callbackManager` ?

Comment: sorry I can't get you I'm new in flutter so can you please elaborate more

Comment: Where you declared variable callbackManager?